# Gimp Brushes Glitch

Tags: gimp, brush, glitch

Hi I faced a problem that when I draw with any brush the result is just filled shape of the brush, there are no shadows and details

tried to fix it by changing the setting but it didn't work

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because you have the Pencil Tool selected, not the Brush Tool. I can see it in the tool bar in your screenshot (see enlargement below).  The Pencil Tool can only draw hard-edged pixels. Select the Brush Tool instead.

[image]